# Events to make a DataGridView ComboxColumn affect the collection of another ComboBox Column

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

You'd think I'd be able to find a code example for this: Let's say I have a WinForm with a DataGridView and 2 ComboBoxColumns. The columns are not databound, they have a static collection for all their options. So I want to programatically change the item collection for Column 2 as changes are made (ie different selections) to Column 1. Any examples for this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is how to register `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler for your `ComboBox` under the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`, we all know that `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` doesn't have such an event. To solve this, we have several ways for `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` with data bound source or static source. Because you said your `Items` are added normally for your combobox so I have this solution:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Control is DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl){
        ((DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)e.Control).SelectedIndexChanged -= SelectedIndexChanged;
        ((DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)e.Control).SelectedIndexChanged += SelectedIndexChanged;
        }
    }
private void SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl combo = sender as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
        //Change the source of the other combobox column accordingly
        //
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }
```

You have to add your code to re-populate the source of the other combobox column accordingly, that's up to you.